# Android GCM. Application not receiving the push notification

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

so after reading a lot of StackOverflow threads on this, with no help, and reading a lot of Google documentation, I am asking here to see if I can get someone to figure out what's wrong..

I have app which should only register with the InstanceID token on my server and be able to get push notifications from GCM.

I am able to get the token and register on my server, but I am not getting the notification to the app.

In the logcat I can see the push is arriving to the device, but not into the app:

```
I/GCM﹕ GCM message com.kazav.gabi.pushtest 0:1442125487591772%7dfbbb577dfbbb57
```

Some of my code:

AndroidMnifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.kazav.gabi.pushtest" >

    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <permission android:name="com.kazav.gabi.pushtest.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" android:protectionLevel="signature" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.kazav.gabi.pushtest.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />


    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <receiver
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmReceiver"
            android:exported="true"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
                <category android:name="com.kazav.gabi.pushtest" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <service
            android:name="com.kazav.gabi.pushtest.TokenReload"
            android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceID"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

        <service
            android:name="com.kazav.gabi.pushtest.PushHendler"
            android:exported="false" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECIEVE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

And my Push handler java file:

PushHendler.java:

```
package com.kazav.gabi.pushtest;

import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.RingtoneManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
import android.util.Log;

import com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmListenerService;

public class PushHendler extends GcmListenerService {


    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(String from, Bundle data) {
        super.onMessageReceived(from, data);
        String message = data.getString("message");
        sendNotification(message);
    }

    private void sendNotification(String message) {
        Log.w("Notification", message);
    }
}
```

I have breakpoint on the onMessageRecieved function but I the app is never going into it..

Do anyone see something wrong with my code?

Thanks,
Gabi.

Comment: did u get the google-services.json file and put in your project?

Comment: @vishnus, Yes I did, put it inside "app" folder, I am getting the project ID from it for the token registration.

Comment: where is the logger that produced I/GCM﹕ GCM message com.kazav.gabi.pushtest 0:1442125487591772%7dfbbb577dfbbb57

Answer (score 0):

I dont see the GCMIntentService of your GCM implementation. You can have a code that acts as a service and use in the Manifest file.

The most important method is something like *generateNotification* that listens for the incoming message through `pending Intent` and generates a notification. Make sure you add that.

Take a look at this code snippet:

```
private static void generateNotification(Context context, String message) {
        int icon = R.drawable.ic_launcher;
        long when = System.currentTimeMillis();
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)
                context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        Notification notification = new Notification(icon, message, when);

        String title = context.getString(R.string.app_name);

        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
        // set intent so it does not start a new activity
        notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP |
                Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
        PendingIntent intent =
                PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
        notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, title, message, intent);
        notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

        // Play default notification sound
        notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;

        // Vibrate if vibrate is enabled
        notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
        notificationManager.notify(0, notification);      

    }
```

For additional information take a look at this [tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/).